# Hide and Seek beat drop symbols translation

Tags: lyrics

https://youtu.be/KR-eV7fHNbM

Do the symbols at 1:30 in that video mean anything?

Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Someone [here on deviant art](https://www.deviantart.com/tom-de-jrad/art/TheFatRat-The-Calling-Language-Translation-600383052) claims to have a translation for all the symbols.  By that reckoning the word above is "SUCESSFULLY" (sic), and the full message is as follows:

> Greetings listener, you now have sucessfully unlocked our code. Thank you for ta ting thu time to do that as a re-ward: you shall re-cieve a treasure that suits your extra ordinary a bil ly ties. Please contact us through listener at the fat rat dot com to claim your re-ward, thank you ver ry (very) much.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I was looking at the word almost at 1:30 in the vid, rather than the one in the shot attached to the question.